# Given the position of a knight and certain pawns in a chessboard, what is the minimum number of jumps the knight has to do to kill all the pawns?

Tags: algorithm, graph, chess, breadth-first-search

In the input we are typing a chessboard of size 8x8, where 'K' is the knight, 'P'(min. 1, and max. 8) is a pawn, and '.' is an empty space. So I know that with one pawn you just need to run a BFS from the knight's initial position to the pawn's position, but what about when we have eight pawns. Of course I could run eight BFS's but that would be really inefficient. What is a more efficient way than running eight BFS's  to find the minimum amount of steps needed to kill all the pawns on the board?

Comment: Minimum Spanning Tree?

Comment: This problem is [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), as the number of state is small (8), you can use bitmask technique to obtain a O(n*n*2^n) time complexity solution with n <= 8.

Answer (score 0):

It is a special case of [Knight's tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) and can be solved in linear time using divide and conquer.

Comment: Linear in what? It sounds much more like a Traveling Salesman problem to me.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Linear in total number of squares. No. It is an instance of TSP, but since this has a restricted search space, it can be solved in polynomial time.